# how to add google auth in quasar capacitor app(android & ios)?

Tags: google-authentication, quasar

how to add google auth in quasar capacitor app(android & ios)?

I try to use this package @reslear/capacitor-google-auth.

It work with in web, but fail in android & ios, it keep pop out the message of not implemented.